# Adding custom folder to Docker using sbt-native-packager in Play JPA project

Tags: jpa, docker, playframework, playframework-2.5, sbt-native-packager

I'm working on a JPA + Playframework 2.5.x project which I package it as Docker image.

I want to forcibly add all the files except one file (META-INF/persistence.xml) under `conf` folder to docker output

Currently I have done the following:

```
mappings in Docker += file("conf/base/application.conf") -> "opt/docker/conf/base/application.conf"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/base/default-client.conf") -> "opt/docker/conf/base/default-client.conf"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/prod/application.conf") -> "opt/docker/conf/prod/application.conf"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/prod/logback.xml") -> "opt/docker/conf/prod/logback.xml"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/stage/application.conf") -> "opt/docker/conf/stage/application.conf"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/stage/logback.xml") -> "opt/docker/conf/stage/logback.xml"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/local/application.conf") -> "opt/docker/conf/local/application.conf"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/local/logback.xml") -> "opt/docker/conf/local/logback.xml"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/routes") -> "opt/docker/conf/routes"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/ValidationMessages.properties") -> "opt/docker/conf/ValidationMessages.properties"
```

I am sure this is not the best way to achieve this. Can anybody suggest better option to customize the Docker output the way I need it ?

My build.sbt file:

```
PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false
name := """wp-pw-ng"""

version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val `wp-pw-ng` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, JavaAppPackaging)

val playVer = "2.5.9"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "5.2.3.Final" exclude("dom4j", "dom4j"),
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.5",
  cache,
  javaWs,
  filters,
  "dom4j" % "dom4j" % "1.6",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "20.0-rc1",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.34"
)

val docDeps = Seq(
  "io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.5.3.2"
)

libraryDependencies ++= docDeps

fork in Test := true
javaOptions in Test ++= Seq(
  "-Xms512M",
  "-Xmx1536M",
  "-Xss1M",
  "-XX:MaxPermSize=384M"
)

fork in run := false

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= (sourceDirectory in Compile) (_ / "resources")

mappings in Docker += file("conf/base/application.conf") -> "opt/docker/conf/base/application.conf"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/base/default-client.conf") -> "opt/docker/conf/base/default-client.conf"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/base/pw.conf") -> "opt/docker/conf/base/paywall.conf"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/prod/application.conf") -> "opt/docker/conf/prod/application.conf"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/prod/logback.xml") -> "opt/docker/conf/prod/logback.xml"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/stage/application.conf") -> "opt/docker/conf/stage/application.conf"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/stage/logback.xml") -> "opt/docker/conf/stage/logback.xml"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/local/application.conf") -> "opt/docker/conf/local/application.conf"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/local/logback.xml") -> "opt/docker/conf/local/logback.xml"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/routes") -> "opt/docker/conf/routes"
mappings in Docker += file("conf/ValidationMessages.properties") -> "opt/docker/conf/ValidationMessages.properties"

//************************************************
// Custom Docker Build,
// use command 'activator docker:publishLocal'
// to publish image locally to computer.
//************************************************
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker._

val playUser = "play"
val grp = "idud"
dockerRepository := Some("quay.io/we")

version in Docker := "latest"

val buildEnv: String = System.getProperty("build.env")

dockerCommands := Seq(
  Cmd("FROM", "anapsix/alpine-java:8_jdk_unlimited"),
  Cmd("RUN", "apk", "-Uuv add", "--no-cache", "su-exec", "groff", "less", "python", "py-pip", "&& pip install awscli ", "&&  apk --purge -v del py-pip ", " &&  rm /var/cache/apk/* "),
  Cmd("RUN", s"addgroup $grp"),
  Cmd("RUN", s"adduser -s /bin/bash -D -G $grp $playUser"),
  Cmd("RUN", "echo", s"'$playUser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL'", ">> /etc/sudoers"),
  Cmd("WORKDIR", "/opt/docker"),
  Cmd("ADD", "opt /opt"),
  Cmd("RUN", "chown", "-R", s"$playUser:$grp", "."),
  Cmd("USER", s"$playUser"),
  Cmd("ENTRYPOINT", "[\"bin/wp-pw-ng\", \"-Dconfig.file=conf/" + buildEnv + "/application.conf\", \"-Dhttp.port=7000\" , \"-Dpidfile.path=/dev/null\"  ,\"-Dlogger.file=conf/" + buildEnv + "/logback.xml\"]"),
  Cmd("EXPOSE", "9877")
)
```

**Additional Info**
I had to resort to this work-around due to issue in build `stage` mode issue with Playframework, [Issue 4590](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4590) and I had to use `PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false` flag in my `build.sbt` file. This would remove all files from `conf` folder in Docker.

Answer (score 2):

The `playExternalizeResources:= false` setting [just prevents sbtfrom adding](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlaySettings.scala#L184-L191) the [playExternalizedResources](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlaySettings.scala#L250-L253) to your `mappings in Universal`, which are the mappings available for all target package formats including docker.

Your build sbt can be lightenend with the [MappingsHelper](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats/universal.html#mappingshelper) ( [ScalaDocs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/latest/api/#com.typesafe.sbt.packager.MappingsHelper$) )

```
import NativePackagerHelper._
mappings in Universal ++= contentOf("conf")
```

You can also filter the mappings to remove the unwanted files, e.g

```
import NativePackagerHelper._
mappings in Universal ++= contentOf("conf").filter(_.2.contains("persistence.xml")
```

Hope that helps,
Muki

Comment: this does not work since within docker stage folder I need the files to be under `opt/docker/conf/` and just plain adding them as `mappings in Docker ++= contentOf("conf")` adds it under `target/stage` folder. I need the files to be remapped under `opt/docker/conf/`

Comment: Then use `directory` instead of `contentOf` and map of the resulting mappings. Like you would do with any other Scala collection

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the files that you want to be mapped inside a `universal/conf` directory. As a result of this, when you're creating the docker image the files get added to the `/opt/docker/conf` directory.